# Border image gets border on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

So I'm trying to create a wordpress page where block will be in that cool border. For that I'm using images. My structure is as followed:

```
<div id="top_border">
<div id="left_border">
<div id="content">
<div id="right_border">
<div id="bottom_border">
```

It all works fine in PC browsers but on mobile devices left and right border get's that weird 1px wide line on each side. See that image:
[image].
Another weird part is that it only happens when I resize that image by height. On the left is working div with small height and on the right is not working with larger height. Here is how I do it in css:

```
left_border{
width:16px;
height:354px;
background: url('left.png') 0px 0px;
float:left;
}
```

I also tried adding that:

```
 {
   border:0 none;
 }
```

But no help.

Any ideas or do you maybe need more info? Page is only available on my local intranet so I can't show it...

Edit: I just figured out that only happens when I set height larger then original height of image. So if image height is 500 and I set height to anything less than 501 it works as soon as I set 501 or more it gets that borders.

Comment: Have you heard of CSS3's [border-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp)?

Comment: I didn't. I will give it a try now, but that doesn't answer my question. Although it may saves me a lot of trouble.

Comment: Well that isn't working in IE and on mobile i get same lines. Now even more...

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer, therefore you have no reason to think it was. It was a tip, nothing more.